# Making unique values into duplicates in R

Tags: duplicates, unique-values

I am working with R and I have a table that look like this...

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

And I need the table to look like this...

```
A
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
C
C
C
C
C
D
D
D
D
D
E
E
E
E
E
F
F
F
F
F
```

So,I need the same values 5 times in order to match them with another column.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the table has associated data that also has to be duplicated.  Looking at a vector or single data.frame column can use `rep`

```
data <- LETTERS[1:6]
rep(data, each = 5)  # will repeat each position 5 times prior to going to next position
rep(data, times = 5)  # will repeat entire array 5 times
```

Comment: Hello again, I have been trying to apply the rep function, but the output that it gives me it is 5 lists with the content of the data frame. In other words I get .. $data 
A B C D E F 
$data
A B C D E F

etc...

I know that it is related to the type of data, but really don't know how to fix it. Maybe I should have said that I am working with a tibble.

Comment: It is ok. I already found a solution. I used the as.vector(dataName$dataColumn). Then apply the rep function as you wrote it and the converted it back to a tibble.